# Can we have more than one Deterministic Finite Automata diagrams for a set of strings?

Tags: automata-theory, fsm

Much like many math equations can be simplified. I am wondering if Deterministic Finite Automata diagrams can equal each other while some may be more simplified than others. I am following the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2cKtLkdwnc) and I am wondering if the graph that I drew with pencil and paper would also be correct. Given the Prompt:

`Construct a DFA that accepts any strings over {a,b} that does not contain the string aabb in it`.

[image]

[image: img1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we have more than one Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) diagrams for a set of strings?

Of course!

[There's also an algorithm to minimize a deterministic finite automata into a *minimal deterministic finite automata*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization). The existence of such algorithm is a proof that for most, if not all, sets of strings, many DFAs can be defined.

Comment: After reading I must agree. Thanks for answering my somewhat obvious question @john